# How to delete an object from array of object in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

```
{
name:"RCB",
image:"rcb.jpg",
players:[
        {
         player:[
                 {
                   name:"Virat Kohli",
                   age:32,
                   Image:"virat.jpg"
                 }
                ]
         }
         ]

}
```

I am trying to delete an object from array of objects.I wanted to delete object with name "Virat Kohli".

```
db.User.updateOne({name:"RCB"},{$pull:{players:{player:{name:"Virat kohli"}}}})
```

I tried with above command but it didn't worked.

Comment: Please paste your example data as text and not as image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to pull the document from nested array:

```
db.collection.update({
    name: "RCB"
  },
  {
    "$pull": {
     "players.$[].player": {
          "name": "Virat Kohli"
         }
     }
  }
)
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/edT_kHqsk_I)